# "Vi o o" em "vi o ocaso" e "via ig" em "devia ignorar" é uma ou duas sílabas métricas?

Tags: pronúncia, fonologia

Aqui há uns tempos pus-me a traduzir por brincadeira um epigrama em versos decassílabos dum conto do Kipling, e deixei uns versos pendurados por causa da métrica.

Eu quero que cada verso tenha dez sílabas métricas, e as minhas dúvidas estão  nos versos abaixo. O (c) é só uma alternativa ao (b). Cada um dos trechos a negrito são uma ou duas sílabas? Ou existe alguma flexibilidade, e podem ser uma ou duas conforme a conveniência?

> (a) **Vi o o**caso antes de os outros verem dia,
> (b) Eu que sei a mais do que de**via ig**norar.
>
> (c) Sá**bio a** mais no que de**via ig**norar.

Deixo aqui as minhas reflexões. Em (a) eu acho que praticamente pronuncio o ***vio o o*** como um tritongo /viwɔ/. Mas isto é uma, duas sílabas, ou há flexibilidade?

Em (b), se fosse ***via*** seguida de consonante, creio que a norma é contarem-se duas sílabas. Mas com ***via ig*** eu não pronuncio o ***a***, e aquilo fica simplesmente um ***i*** arrastado ou talvez dois ***ii*** separados por um hiato quase impercetível. Novamente é uma ou duas sílabas?

No (c) inclino-me mais para o ***bio a*** ser só uma sílaba. Mas digam de vossa justiça.

Se quiserem ver, o original está [aqui](https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/k/kipling/rudyard/lifes/chapter20.html). E se quiserem ver como é que o Camões fazia, têm aqui [Os Lusíadas](http://www.citi.pt/ciberforma/ana_paulos/ficheiros/lusiadas.pdf) que é todo em versos decassílabos.

Comment: falta uma palavra: "cada um [dos?] trechos"

Comment: Não podem ser três sílabas métricas, também? Pessoalmente, parece-me que mais facilmente vejo 3 sílabas do que 1.

Comment: @ANeves Em nenhum dos casos tens três sílabas métricas. Se tu ali contas três, quantas sílabas métricas contas em "A Fé, o Império, e as terras viciosas". A resposta certa é dez; é dos Lusíadas. Parece-me que *Impé**rio e as*** forma uma única sílaba.

Comment: Nao podia ser: `A Fé, o Im pé rio.e.as ter ras vi cio (sas)`.  `Vi.o.o ca so an tes de.os ou tros ve rem (dia)`?

Comment: @Bruno Se compreendo bem a tua divisão silábica, no verso do Camões  tens 11 ou 12 sílabas, o que não pode ser: Os Lusíadas são em versos de 10 sílabas. E eu acho que é vi.ci.o.sas, mas não tenho a certeza. Em *império e as* o ***e*** não forma sílaba sozinho: no mínimo junta-se com *as*. No meu verso, não podes excluir *dia*, porque *dia* é tónico.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[A wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9trica_(poesia)) explica como se deve proceder á contagem das silabas métricas.

Em suma ela é igual á divisão silábica, com algumas regras especiais.

No artigo pode encontrar as 3 regras aplicadas:

> 1. Não se contam as sílabas poéticas que estejam após a última sílaba tônica do verso
> 2. Ditongos têm valor de uma só sílaba poética.
> 3. Duas ou mais vogais, átonas ou até mesmo tônicas, podem fundir-se entre uma palavra e outra, formando uma só sílaba poética.

Um problema que eu vi na pergunta do Jacinto é que ele não referiu qualquer problema de contagem em "caso antes" nem em "de os outros".

A divisão silábica métrica é respetivamente `"ca so.an tes"` e `"de.os tros"`. (Eu denotei com "." a junção de duas silabas numa silaba métrica).

O verso `"Vi o ocaso antes de os outros verem dia"` seria dividido da seguinte forma:

> "Vi.o.o(1) ca(2) so.an(3) tes(4) de.os(5) ou(6) tros(7) ve(8) rem(9)
>   dia(10)"

O mesmo pode ser dito em relação a "devia ignorar" é aplicada a 3<sup>a</sup> regra. Até certo pode pode ser até equiparada á situação de `"caso antes"`.

> "de via.ig no rar"

Nestas situacoes o mais estranho parece ser estarem consoantes envolvidas no processo de separação... Mas são tão validos como em "de os"

[Encontrei uma ferramenta online](http://www.separarensilabas.com/index-pt.php) para fazer a separação de silabas métricas, para referencia futura.

Comment: Então ótimo: é só uma sílaba como eu queria. Se bem que como um separador automático uma pessoa fica um bocado na dúvida. O meu problema com *vi o ocaso* é que embora o primeiro ***o*** de ocaso seja átono, tem timbre aberto, o que faz sobressair mais. Não mencionei o *oca**so an**tes* e ***de os***, porque aí tinha a certeza que aquilo se juntava tudo numa só sílaba métrica. Já agora, podes incluir uma nota sobre o *devia ignorar*.

Comment: @Jacinto Editei

Answer (score 1):

Até é possível dividir ***vio o o*** em uma sílaba somente, mas não sem tornar o verso duro, na minha opinião. Como diz Miguel do Couto Guerreiro no seu Tratado de versificação portuguesa:

> "Se a vogal precedente se alongar,
>   Não tem a sinalefa então lugar."

Não vejo outra possibilidade, segundo as regras da boa poesia, a não ser dividir o seu primeiro verso como

> Vi oo ca soan tes deos u tros ve rem dia

Veja estes exemplos retirados de Nicolau Tolentino e Alvarenga Peixoto, respectivamente:

> "Eu vi a Márcia bela, vi Cupido,
>   Com arcos, setas e cruel aljava."
>
> "Eu vi a linda Jônia e, namorado,
>   Fiz logo eterno voto de querê-la."

Note como não se faz sinalefa com o "i" de "vi" para o artigo que se lhe segue.

Escandiria b) do seguinte modo:

> Eu que sei a mais do que de vi aig no rar

Ou ainda

> Eu que sei a mais do que de vi a ig no rar

Embora o primeiro jeito me agrade mais.

Quanto a c), também separaria ***bio a*** numa só sílaba. A escansão em duas sílabas é possível, mas isso resultaria num verso frouxo.

> "Frouxo será o verso quando, para chegar à medida, for necessário
>   deixar hiatos, isto é, quando se não absorver uma vogal que devera
>   sumir-se noutra".
>
> Antonio Feliciano de Castilho, *Tratado de metrificação portugueza*.

E, para finalizar, deixo aqui uma tentativa de tradução desses versos, para caso lhe seja útil:

> Antes que o dia vissem, vi o ocaso,
>   Sábio demais no que ignorar devera.

@edit

Tradução em oitava rima:

> Colhi autúnea messe antes de Abril,
>   E os campos me dourou precoce grão;
>   O ano, a meu pesar, me descobriu
>   Mistérios que cerrou do Fado a mão;
>   Num místico senoide se imergiu,
>   Exânime e sem flor, cada estação:
>    Vi antes d'alva o declinar do dia,
>    Sábio demais no que ignorar devia.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Também prefiro "sábio demais" a "sábio a mais", mas terminar em "devera" arruína-me a rima. Os meus versos anteriores são "O ano abriu seus segredos pra meu azar. / Deflorada, cada estação jazia, / Num mistério de viço e da agonia". Podia pôr "ignorar devia" e passava a rimar em "-ia"; ficava era um "-ar" sem rimar com nada. A terminação em "ocaso" também não rima. Uma solução é "os mais" em vez de "os outros"; não é tão imediatamente compreensível.

Comment: Como você dividiu o verso "O ano abriu seus segredos pra meu azar"? Eu contei onze sílabas aqui. O verso seguinte tem a medida certa, porém as sílabas tônicas não estão nas posições corretas (veja [este link][1]). Minha sugestão: Sem fruto ou flor, cada estação jazia. Voltando a a), sem mudar a consoante, outra possibilidade seria: Vi antes d'alva o declinar do dia. 

  [1]: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verso_decass%C3%ADlabo

Comment: Não consegui traduzir o poema usando o esquema de rimas que você escolheu, mas adicionei ao final da minha resposta uma versão em oitava rima. Não leio muita poesia em inglês, então fiz com base no que eu entendi dos versos de Kipling...

Comment: Dividi "o a.no a.briu . seus . se.gre.dos . pra . meu a.zar". Fiz provavlemente um sinalefa que tu não fazes. Eu mantive a rima do original: aabcccb.