# Qual o exato significado de "estudo" neste contexto?

Tags: significado-em-contexto

Gostaria de saber qual exatamente o significado de “estudo” nestes dois exemplos retirados da literatura portuguesa:

> 1. “E em fingir, por temor, empenha estudo”;
> 2. “Vãmente fazes de
>      iludir-me estudo / Que o ouvir-te um novo amor me não concede”.

Como seria uma paráfrase do primeiro exemplo?

Comment: Estudo é estudo. Mas seria interessante saber que obras, etc. Um pouco de contexto....

Comment: @Lambie A primeira citação é o terceiro verso do primeiro terceto deste poema de Bocage: http://www.casadobruxo.com.br/poesia/b/bocage26.htm

Comment: "Acode ao mortal, que frio e mudo, Oculta o pátrio amor, torce a verdade, E em fingir, por temor, empenha estudo": está dirigindo-se à liberdade. O  poeta pede a liberdade de acodar ao mortal (homen). Esse mesmo homen finge na vida porque tem medo e como resultado ele  poê em penhor o estudo. Ou seja: usa o estudo [da liberdade?] como garantía mas talvez não tem liberdade na sua própria vida. Acho que poderia ser por aí.

Comment: Era importante ler o  poema para saber que se está falando "a" liberdade. Se você põe algo em penhor, você usa um bem como garantia do empréstimo. Me parece que aqui o homen não gozará da libertade porque está estudando-a.

Comment: Credo, queria dizer: liberdade. :)

Comment: @Sasaki, encontrei uma definição e exemplo de "estudo" num dicionário de 1789, contemporâneo dos poemas, que se ajusta como uma luva aos teus exemplos. Incluí na resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O significado exato de ***estudo*** nestes poemas compreende-se melhor recorrendo a um dicionário contemporâneo deles, o [Morais Silva de 1789](https://books.google.pt/books?id=4gVdAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA573&lpg=PA573&dq=%22saber%20aver-se%20em%20alguma%20coisa%22&source=bl&ots=mwU1DKg0R6&sig=vmJvsBZd7guFSDsfycb00CQPFAQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjppuPZscTbAhUKbxQKHZlJCRAQ6AEIMzAC#v=onepage&q=%22saber%20aver-se%20em%20alguma%20coisa%22&f=false) (negrito meu em todas as citações; grafia original):

> ESTUDO […] § Reflexão para saber aver-se em alguma coisa *v.g.,, **faço estudo de agradar-lhe** ,, todo o seu estudo he como enriquecer.* § Cuidado, e applicação em qualquer coisa.

Ou seja, *estudo* é aqui a aplicação das faculdades intelectuais para lidar com um situação (“aver-se em alguma coisa”) ou conseguir algo, como agradar a alguém ou enriquecer. No nosso caso, é a aplicação das faculdades intelectuais para fingir (primeiro poema), e para iludir o poeta (segundo poema). O que o Morais Silva escreve a seguir, “cuidado e aplicação em qualquer coisa”, é praticamente o mesmo. E isso já se encontra nos dicionários atuais, que também dizem que *estudo* pode significar ‘dissimulação’, que também se aplica aos presentes exemplos, dado que o objetivo é “fingir” e “iludir”. Encontram estas aceções no
[Michaelis (7 e 9)], e eu cito o Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002):

> **estudo** […] **8** *fig.* cuidado, atenção especial <*emprega estudo em agradar*> **9** *fig.* dissimulação, disfarce, maneira afetada de fazer ir dizer algo.

*Estudo*, na sua aceção mais geral, é aplicação das faculdades intelectuais para aprender algo. Nestas aceções é aplicar as faculdades intelectuais para conseguir algo; agir de forma estudada, em vez de agir espontaneamente.

O significado do verso fica mais claro se o virmos em contexto. O primeiro é do soneto [*Liberdade* de Bocage](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/literatura/iluminismo.htm). O verso pode ser parafraseado em, “por temor, tem cuidado, atenção especial em fingir”. Na verdade, usando as palavras originais, mas numa ordem mais normal, já se compreende melhor (mas deixa de rimar), “por temor, empenha estudo em fingir”:

> Liberdade, onde estás? Quem te demora?
> Quem faz que o teu influxo em nós não caia?
> Porque (triste de mim!) porque não raia
> Já na esfera de Lísia a tua aurora?
>
> Da santa redenção é vinda a hora
> A esta parte do mundo que desmaia.
> Oh! Venha... Oh! Venha, e trémulo descaia
> Despotismo feroz, que nos devora!
>
> Eia! Acode ao mortal, que, frio e mudo,
> Oculta o pátrio amor, torce a vontade,
> **E em fingir, por temor, empenha estudo.**
>
> Movam nossos grilhões tua piedade;
> Nosso númen tu és, e glória, e tudo,
> Mãe do génio e prazer, oh Liberdade!

O segundo, quase que desistia de o achar, mas lá o encontrei nestas [*Composições Poeticas offerecidas ao Serenissimo Senhor Dom Joaõ* por Curvo Semedo (Lisboa, 1803, p. 39)](https://archive.org/stream/composicespoetic00seme#page/n59/mode/2up/search/illudir-me+estudo). Reproduzo-o abaixo. O poeta fala de uma Ilvia (ou será Ílvia) impostora e traidora que tenta reconquistar o amor dele, e acusa-a de o tentar iludir a ele, o poeta. Aqui podemos pensar que também há um alteração da ordem normal das palavras para efeito da rima; a ordem mais natural seria  “fazes estudo de iludir-me”, ou seja, “fazes reflexão, cuidado especial em tentar iludir-me” (“estudo de iludir-me” pode parecer estranho, mas notem o “estudo de agradar-lhe” do Morais Silva); ou então podemos manter a ordem, e seria “tornas a tentativa de iludir-me em estudo; a tentativa de iludir-me é para ti um estudo”, isto é, reflexão, cuidado especial; comparem com o “todo o seu estudo era como enriquecer” do Morais Silva.

[image]
[*Composições Poeticas offerecidas ao Serenissimo Senhor Dom Joaõ, Principe Regente de Portugal,* por Curvo Semedo (Lisboa, 1803, p. 39)](https://archive.org/stream/composicespoetic00seme#page/n59/mode/2up/search/illudir-me+estudo)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. A propósito, se não for muito inômodo, o convido a visitar esta pergunta que fiz já há algum tempo e para a qual ainda não obtive resposta: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/4948/qual-o-significado-da-express%C3%A3o-por-mi%C3%BAdo-e-grosso-neste-contexto. Talvez você saiba o significado da expressão, retirada de um soneto de Bocage. De qualquer forma, obrigado novamente.

Comment: @Sasaki, sempre às ordens! Essa do "por miúdo e grosso" nem foi das mais difíceis :) És um estudioso do Bocage?

Comment: No Brasil diríamos "no atacado e no varejo". Nunca tinha ouvido essa expressão antes. O recurso a um dicionário da época é realmente uma excelente ideia. Já baixei o do Morais Silva aqui. Ah, também faço versos, e Bocage é uma inspiração. Aqui um soneto meu, caso se interesse em ler: https://pt.scribd.com/document/381533075/Soneto-A-Sina.

Comment: @Sasaki, ah! genial! Espero que a desdita não dure sempre :) Aqui em Portugal ainda se diz "vender por grosso" (e correspondentemente temos os "grossistas"); "por miúdo" ia lá só por comparação com "por grosso". Eu tenho aqui no meta [uma porção de links a dicionários antigos](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288/resources-for-etymological-research-recursos-para-investiga%C3%A7%C3%A3o-etimol%C3%B3gica). És capaz de estar interessado.

Comment: @Sasaki, portanto, tu deves perceber alguma coisas de métrica. Queres dar uma olhada a [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3922/vi-o-o-em-vi-o-ocaso-e-via-ig-em-devia-ignorar-%C3%A9-uma-ou-duas-s%C3%ADlabas-m%C3%A9t)?

Answer (score 0):

Mais opinião que análise linguística, ambas soam como: razão, racionalidade, busca pela verdade, realidade.

*OBS: O link http://www.casadobruxo.com.br/poesia/b/bocage26.htm contem uma reprodução com alguns erros exemplo "númem" ao invés de "númen", ":" ao invés de "." logo após a palavra estudo.*

Comment: Creio que o contexto dos versos dá uma perspetiva diferente à palavra *estudo*.