# Qual o significado da expressão "por miúdo e grosso" neste contexto?

Tags: significado, significado-em-contexto

Gostaria de saber o significado da expressão “por miúdo e grosso” na seguinte estrofe de um [soneto de Bocage](http://purl.pt/1276/1/poemas3.html) (negrito meu):

> [...]
>   Dos esburgados peitos quase aberto,
>   Versos impinge **por miúdo e grosso**;
>   E do que em frase vil chamam caroço,
>   Se o quer, é *vox clamantis in deserto.*
>   [...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Versos impinge por miúdo e grosso” é uma metáfora comercial: *versos impinge a retalho e por atacado*. As expressões *vender **por miúdo*** (‘a retalho, varejo, em pequenas quantidades’) e *vender **em grosso*** (‘por atacado, em grande quantidade’) aparecem no dicionário de Moraes Silva de 1789, contemporâneo de Bocage (grafia original; negrito meu):

> MIÚDO , adj. pequeno , de pouco volume […] § *Vender **por miúdo*** , ou *em retalho* , opposto a vender *em partidas* , ou *em grosso* , ou *por junto.*
>   [Moraes Silva, *Diccionario da Lingua Portugueza*, tomo II 1789.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=KvFj2p9f8RgC&pg=RA1-PA87&lpg=RA1-PA87&dq=%22Vender%20por%20mi%C3%BAdo,%20ou%20em%20retalbo%20,%20oppofto%20a%20vender%20em%20partidas,%20ou%20em%20gro/o!,%20ou%20por%20junto%22&source=bl&ots=-2Wmv0d9Qi&sig=KrF_fD5VqSGGjBtX2pcQgFgUYrE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVvbbR98jbAhWJcRQKHZJnA0kQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22Vender%20por%20mi%C3%BAdo%2C%20ou%20em%20retalbo%20%2C%20oppofto%20a%20vender%20em%20partidas%2C%20ou%20em%20gro%2Fo!%2C%20ou%20por%20junto%22&f=false)
>
> GROSSO, s. m. A maior porção […] § ***Em grosso*** , oppõe se a *por miúdo* *v. g.* ,, contratar , comprar , vender em grosso
>   [Moraes Silva, *Diccionario da Lingua Portugueza*, tomo I, 1789.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=kPBDAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA671&lpg=PA671&dq=%22Em%20grofo,%20opp%C3%B5e%20fe%20a%20por%20mitido%22&source=bl&ots=EvXzu6no5M&sig=1EWtvabf7ewdPOjUPdfohyT5vac&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJtvWC8sjbAhVNnRQKHVFtDG8Q6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22Em%20grofo%2C%20opp%C3%B5e%20fe%20a%20por%20mitido%22&f=false)

Ainda se diz com o mesmo significado *vender em grosso* no Brasil, enquanto que em Portugal passou a ser *por grosso* [(Priberam)](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/grosso). Já *vender por miúdo* parece ter caído em desuso. Não encontro isso nem nos dicionários online (e.g. [Priberram](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/grosso), nem no Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002), nem no da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (2001).

Creio que no verso seguinte, *caroço* significa ‘dinheiro’. Embora não tenha encontrado este significado nos dicionários da época, no [*Thesouro da Lingua Portugueza* de 1873](https://books.google.pt/books?id=sWzh2uSTUQUC&pg=PA117&dq=%22Figurada%20e%20popularmente%20dinheiro%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWuM6xjMnbAhUjNX0KHZRPDDQQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22Figurada%20e%20popularmente%20dinheiro%22&f=false) já vem. Então o Bocage diz que que tenta vender versos a retalho e por atacado, mas se quer dinheiro, ele, Bocage, é uma voz clamando no deserto, ou seja, ninguém o ouve [(alusão ao profeta Isaías)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vox_clamantis_in_deserto).